# How to generate code for groovy-wslite from a wsdl?

Tags: soap, groovy

Is there an easy way to generate code for groovy-wslite from a wsdl? Similar to wsimport from JaxWS we would like to generate the code for the send/envelopes for several dozen services. Any ideas, trick, libraries, or tools we can use?

Comment: It looks like there is no Groovy way to work with SOAP anymore. Using Grails 2.2 and JDK 1.7 I tried Groovy SOAP but that will not generate the methods and was deprecated 2008. GroovyWS has a compilation problem with 1.7 and was deprecated 2010. Groovy-WSlite works but requires configurations for each endpoint (this was the reason for the question above). Currently, I use jaxws-rt but need to generate the Stubs via Ant each time an endpoint changes. Are ther other ways to access SOAP Endpoints - especially Groovy ones (i.e., pointing to an Endpoint and generating the Stubs on the fly)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at [Groovy SOAP](http://groovy.jmiguel.eu/groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+SOAP.html)?
Groovy makes it easier than with JaxWE to handle SOAP webservices. Something like:

```
def myService = new SoapClient("myNiceWSDLURL")
def result = myService.method(param1, param2)
```

Comment: I tried it but I had compilation errors (it seems to require Java 1.5 and I use 1.7) and the website says it is deprecated.